# Alternative Android Emulators if processor doesn't support Virtualization Technology

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I would like to configure an `emulator` to test my android app on different screen resolutions. I tried installing `intelhaxm` but it failed with the famous error

> "This Computer doesn't support Intel virtualisation Technology
>   (VT-x).HAXM cannot be installed "

I spent some time understanding the error, and installed `Intel Processor Identification Utility` to check whether my processor really has virtualisation capability (Mine is pretty old) and it showed it does NOT have.

[image]

Then I started looking for alternatives and found the below.

1. `Bluestacks` - I installed it and could able to use as a emulator. But problem is, it `does not have pre-configured devices` like the android studio emulator has. It could not help me.
2. `GenyMotion` - I tried this too, but failed to open saying `Unable to load virtual box engine`. Then I installed oracle VM virtual box, later I came to know that it requires some OS to be installed and failed with `No Bootable medium found and System halted.`

I already spent significant time experimenting these, want to know if there is any better emulator I can give a try next?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why not use a real device?

Comment: I used my device so far. But when I installed my app on other devices, some functionalities are not working properly. I want to encounter those

Comment: Seems like quite a problem... You'd probably need to invest in a newer CPU :/

Comment: @Vucko I wish to :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ARM emulator images with the standard Android SDK emulator. They do not require HAXM, the way the x86 an x86-64 images do. However, the ARM images are *slow*.